# Static link to ATL always fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, mfc, atl

I use some ATL functions to create a Media control, but it seems that I can only use Dynamic link to ATL option. When I switch to Static link to ATL, I just can't create the control successfully.

I'm so confused. Anyone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
//related headers
#include <wmp.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlhost.h>
#include <atlctl.h>

//related vars
CAxWindow  m_wndView;  // ActiveX host window class.    CComPtr<IWMPPlayer>  
m_spWMPPlayer;  // Smart pointer to IWMPPlayer interface.

//related function code:
CComPtr<IAxWinHostWindow>  spHost;
HRESULT  hr;
m_wndView.Create(m_hWnd, rect, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
hr = m_wndView.QueryHost(&spHost);
/*
when I switch to "Static Link to ATL" option, I will fail here
E_FAIL == hr;//the failure flag
*/
if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return FALSE;

hr = spHost->CreateControl(CComBSTR(_T("{6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}")), m_wndView, 0);
if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return FALSE;

hr = m_wndView.QueryControl(&m_spWMPPlayer);
if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return FALSE;
```

Comment: S_FAIL == hr;//the failure flag

Comment: There is no such thing as `S_FAIL`. It could have been `E_FAIL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Static Link to ATL, you have to use the preprocessor: _ATL_DLL,

You can set it here: Property Pages | C/C++ | Preprocessor